# Which IsValid method should I override when implementing custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: .net, entity-framework, validation, attributes

When I implement a custom attribute inherited from ValidationAttribute class, I've always overrided `bool IsValid(object value)` method disgarding the other one whose prototype is `ValidationResult IsValid(objet value, ValidationContext validationContext)`.

Maybe, I should override the second method instead even if I don't use validation context or the result (I use validation with EntityFramework and `ModelState.IsValid` controller property). Or continue to disregard the overloaded method. If then, could I have an object valid or invalid depending on the context the attribute validation is invoked? Is a situation as shown in the code bellow problematic?

```
class StrictlyPreviousAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var dateTime = value as DateTime?;
        return dateTime == null || dateTime <= DateTime.Today;
    }
}

class PreviousAttribute : StrictlyPreviousAttribute 
{
    public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dateTime = value as DateTime?;

        if(dateTime == DateTime.Today)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsValid(object);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is there object misconception or if I'm missing some point. Is there a method I should preferably override instead of the other. Should I override both.

Comment: ValidationContext makes it easy to access other properties and was added in .NET 4.0. Here is a good description: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

Comment: @SteveGreene I posted the relevant part from the link you provided. The credit of the answer should be yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link provided by Steve Greene in the comment above enlighten the difference between the methods and answer the question.

The method returning a `bool` still exist for backward compatibility but is not abstract anymore since .NET 4.0. It is advised to override the method that have access to the `ValidationContext`.

> This (amongst other things) gives us
>   access to the whole model even when the validator is at the property
>   level. The massive advantage of using a property level validator is
>   that the error is set against the property itself instead of the class
>   removing the requirement to use an Html.ValidationSummary. Since the
>   validation error is set against the property correctly, your normal
>   <del>Html.ValidationFor</del> Html.ValidationMessageFor helpers will pick up and display the error against
>   the invalid form field.

It has been written a while ago (with ASP.NET MVC 3) but remains valid with .NET 4.6 framework. Also, I implemented unit tests for the `bool IsValid(object value)` method. The tests continue to pass even if I only override the method with the `ValidationContext` parameter.

Comment: The method for displaying property validation error is Html.ValidationMessageFor not Html.ValidationFor, it is a mistake

Comment: Corrected! It might be a confusion between `ValidationMessageFor` and `ValidateFor` extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs#L305), the overload returning a bool is deprecated and you should only override the overload that takes a ValidationContext:

```cs
        /// Derived classes should not override this method as it is only available for backwards compatibility.
        /// Instead, implement <see cref="IsValid(object, ValidationContext)"/>.
```

Unfortunately, at the time of writing this, that deprecation comment hasn't made it into the documentation yet.